Solve inverse functions not found, use Reduce for tensioned membrane with pressure load, Reduce not work. MMA Solution not match published solution
I am attempting to replicate results from a published paper titled: DEFLECTION AND MAXIMUM STRESS ON RECTANGULAR MEMBRANES. I working on the simple case of a square membrane. The equations are straight forward and a analytical solution is presented in the paper =>LINK below.  The paper was published in 1994 +/- and I have to believe that MMA can replicate the analytical results produced back then. Maybe my approach is incorrect.
https://drive.proton.me/urls/BCC6HV4B0M#zCHyD1wJbl41
The solution process is to calculate  the total strain energy from an assumed set of displacements. The displacements have trig functions which I suspect are causing the solution problem.  I tried using REDUCE as suggested by MMA, but without any success. I tried using the INACTIVE command to see if that could resolve the problem, not any success that I could see.
(*Constants and Dimensions*)
(*

Solution of stretched SQUARE membrane.
DFLECTION
MAXIMUM STRESS 

REF: 

TECHNICAL SUPPORT PACKAGE
GODDARD SPACE FLIGHT CENTER 
NASA TECH BRIEFS
GSC-13561

*)
(*  aa =  1/2 of each side of the square membrane, total side dim = \
2aa *)
(*  EE= Young's Modulus*)
(* hh= Thickness of the plate*)
(*vv=Poisson's Ratio*)
(* px=Preload in x direction*)
(*py=Preload in y direction*)
(*wo=Amplitude of initial displacement*)
(*ccu=Parameter to be optimized*)
(*wo=Parameter to be detmined for deflection mag.*)

(*Define assumed displacement Functions  w is out of membrane plane, \
u and v are in plane displacements *)
wsak[x_, y_] := 
 woo*Cos[(Pi*x)/(2*aa)]*Cos[(Pi*y)/(2*aa)] (* REF EQ 5 *)
usak[x_, y_] := ccu*Sin[(Pi*x)/aa]*Cos[(Pi*y)/(2*aa)]  (* REF EQ 6 *)
vsak[x_, y_] := ccu*Sin[(Pi*y)/aa]*Cos[(Pi*x)/(2*aa)] (* REF EQ 7 *)

(* Tension Preloading effects along the edges in x and y direction, p \
= pli units *)
delta1x[x_] := (px*x)/(2*EE*hh*aa)  (* REF EQ 8 *)
delta2y[y_] := (py*y)/(2*EE*hh*aa) (* REF EQ 9 *)

(* add in plane preload displacements to the assumed in plane \
displacement functions, note wsak remains same as above *)
utsak[x_, y_] := 
 usak[x, y] + delta1x[x]  (* REF EQ 11  - total edge displacement *)
vtsak[x_, y_] := 
 vsak[x, y] + delta2y[y]  (* REF EQ 12   - total edge displacement *)


(* fully write out all functions into 1 combined function *)
wsakl[x_, y_] := wo*Cos[(Pi*x)/(2*aa)]*Cos[(Pi*y)/(2*aa)]
utsakl[x_, y_] := 
 ccu*Sin[(Pi*x)/aa]*Cos[(Pi*y)/(2*aa)] + (px*x)/(2*EE*hh*aa)
vtsakl[x_, y_] := 
 ccu*Sin[(Pi*y)/aa]*Cos[(Pi*x)/(2*aa)] + (py*y)/(2*EE*hh*aa)

(* find the strain components for the assumed displacement functions *)

epx[x_, y_] := 
 D[utsak[x, y], x] + 1/2*D[wsak[x, y], x]^2   (* REF EQ 2 *)
epy[x_, y_] := 
 D[vtsak[x, y], y] + 1/2*D[wsak[x, y], y]^2  (* REF EQ 3 *)
epxy[x_, y_] := 
 D[utsak[x, y], y] + D[vtsak[x, y], x] + 
  D[wsak[x, y], x]*D[wsak[x, y], y]   (* REF EQ 4 *)

(* try to simplify expressions *)
epxs[x_, y_] := Simplify[D[utsak[x, y], x] + 1/2*D[wsak[x, y], x]^2]
epys[x_, y_] := Simplify[D[vtsak[x, y], y] + 1/2*D[wsak[x, y], y]^2]
epxys[x_, y_] := 
 Simplify[
  D[utsak[x, y], y] + D[vtsak[x, y], x] + 
   D[wsak[x, y], x]*D[wsak[x, y], y]]

(* fully write out all functions into 1 combined function -do not \
depend on soltion using previous defined function - no nesting trial  \
*)
epxsl[x_, y_] := 
 Simplify[
  D[ccu*Sin[(Pi*x)/aa]*Cos[(Pi*y)/(2*aa)] + (px*x)/(2*EE*hh*aa), x] + 
   1/2*D[wo*Cos[(Pi*x)/(2*aa)]*Cos[(Pi*y)/(2*aa)], x]^2]

epysl[x_, y_] := 
 Simplify[
  D[ccu*Sin[(Pi*y)/aa]*Cos[(Pi*x)/(2*aa)] + (py*y)/(2*EE*hh*aa), y] + 
   1/2*D[wo*Cos[(Pi*x)/(2*aa)]*Cos[(Pi*y)/(2*aa)], y]^2]

epxysl[x_, y_] := 
 Simplify[
  D[ccu*Sin[(Pi*x)/aa]*Cos[(Pi*y)/(2*aa)] + (px*x)/(2*EE*hh*aa), y] + 
   D[ccu*Sin[(Pi*y)/aa]*Cos[(Pi*x)/(2*aa)] + (py*y)/(2*EE*hh*aa), x] +
    D[wo*Cos[(Pi*x)/(2*aa)]*Cos[(Pi*y)/(2*aa)], x]*
    D[wo*Cos[(Pi*x)/(2*aa)]*Cos[(Pi*y)/(2*aa)], y]]


VVV[ccu_] := 
 Inactivate[((EE*hh)/(2*(1 - vv^2)))*
   Integrate[
    Integrate[
     epx[x, y]^2 + epy[x, y]^2 + 
      2*vv*epx[x, y]*epy[x, y] + ((1/2)/(1 - vv))*
       epxy[x, y]^2, {y, -aa, aa}], {x, -aa, aa}], Integrate]
dVVVdc = D[VVV[ccu], ccu]; (* find 1 st der  wrt ccu *)
equationToSolve = dVVVdc == 0; (* set eq for solve of ccu *)
equationToSolve = Simplify[dVVVdc == 0]; (* try Simplify for ccu *)

(*Solve for ccu*)
solution = Solve[equationToSolve, ccu]
Print[]
Print[" print solution "]


Print[]
Print[" try inactivate command "]

VDV[ccu_] := 
 Inactivate[(EE*hh)/(2*(1 - vv^2))*
   Integrate[
    Integrate[
     epx[x, y]^2 + epy[x, y]^2 + 
      2*vv*epx[x, y]*epy[x, y] + (1 - vv)/2*epxy[x, y]^2, {y, -aa, 
      aa}], {x, -aa, aa}], Integrate]
dVVV1dc = D[VDV[ccu], ccu];
equationToSolve2 = dVVV1dc == 0;


Print[]
Print[" using solve for ccu *** "]
Print[]
solution1 = Solve[equationToSolve2, ccu]
Simplify[solution1]
Print[]
Print[" using reduce for ccu "]
Print[]
solution1 = Reduce[equationToSolve2, ccu]
Print[]
Print[]
Print[]



Inactivate[(EE*hh)/(2*(1 - vv^2))*
  Integrate[
   Integrate[
    epx[x, y]^2 + epy[x, y]^2 + 
     2*vv*epx[x, y]*epy[x, y] + (1 - vv)/2*epxy[x, y]^2, {y, -aa, 
     aa}], {x, -aa, aa}]]



It is not clear what do you try to do. Is this code to compute ccu?

To compute ccu we can use your code with small modifications
(*Constants and Dimensions*)
(*Solution of stretched SQUARE membrane.DFLECTION MAXIMUM STRESS \
REF:TECHNICAL SUPPORT PACKAGE GODDARD SPACE FLIGHT CENTER NASA TECH \
BRIEFS GSC-13561*)
(*aa=1/2 of each side of the square membrane,total side dim=2aa*)
(*EE=Young's Modulus*)
(*hh=Thickness of the plate*)
(*vv=Poisson's Ratio*)
(*px=Preload in x direction*)
(*py=Preload in y direction*)
(*wo=Amplitude of initial displacement*)
(*ccu=Parameter to be optimized*)
(*wo=Parameter to be determined for deflection mag.*)

(*Define assumed displacement Functions w is out of membrane plane,u \
and v are in plane displacements*)
wsak[x_, y_] := woo*Cos[(Pi*x)/(2*aa)]*Cos[(Pi*y)/(2*aa)] (*REF EQ 5*)
usak[x_, y_] := ccu*Sin[(Pi*x)/aa]*Cos[(Pi*y)/(2*aa)]  (*REF EQ 6*)
vsak[x_, y_] := ccu*Sin[(Pi*y)/aa]*Cos[(Pi*x)/(2*aa)] (*REF EQ 7*)

(*Tension Preloading effects along the edges in x and y \
direction,p=pli units*)
delta1x[x_] := (px*x)/(2*EE*hh*aa)  (*REF EQ 8*)
delta2y[y_] := (py*y)/(2*EE*hh*aa) (*REF EQ 9*)

(*add in plane preload displacements to the assumed in plane \
displacement functions,note wsak remains same as above*)
utsak[x_, y_] := 
 usak[x, y] + delta1x[x]  (*REF EQ 11-total edge displacement*)
vtsak[x_, y_] := 
 vsak[x, y] + delta2y[y]  (*REF EQ 12-total edge displacement*)


(*fully write out all functions into 1 combined function*)
wsakl[x_, y_] := wo*Cos[(Pi*x)/(2*aa)]*Cos[(Pi*y)/(2*aa)]
utsakl[x_, y_] := 
 ccu*Sin[(Pi*x)/aa]*Cos[(Pi*y)/(2*aa)] + (px*x)/(2*EE*hh*aa)
vtsakl[x_, y_] := 
 ccu*Sin[(Pi*y)/aa]*Cos[(Pi*x)/(2*aa)] + (py*y)/(2*EE*hh*aa)

(*find the strain components for the assumed displacement functions*)

epx[x_, y_] := 
 D[utsak[x, y], x] + 1/2*D[wsak[x, y], x]^2   (*REF EQ 2*)
epy[x_, y_] := D[vtsak[x, y], y] + 1/2*D[wsak[x, y], y]^2  (*REF EQ 3*)
epxy[x_, y_] := 
 D[utsak[x, y], y] + D[vtsak[x, y], x] + 
  D[wsak[x, y], x]*D[wsak[x, y], y]   (*REF EQ 4*)

(*try to simplify expressions*)
epxs[x_, y_] := Evaluate[D[utsak[x, y], x] + 1/2*D[wsak[x, y], x]^2]
epys[x_, y_] := Evaluate[D[vtsak[x, y], y] + 1/2*D[wsak[x, y], y]^2]
epxys[x_, y_] := 
 Evaluate[
  D[utsak[x, y], y] + D[vtsak[x, y], x] + 
   D[wsak[x, y], x]*D[wsak[x, y], y]]

(*fully write out all functions into 1 combined function-do not \
depend on soltion using previous defined function-no nesting trial*)
epxsl[x_, y_] := 
 Evaluate[
  D[ccu*Sin[(Pi*x)/aa]*Cos[(Pi*y)/(2*aa)] + (px*x)/(2*EE*hh*aa), x] + 
   1/2*D[wo*Cos[(Pi*x)/(2*aa)]*Cos[(Pi*y)/(2*aa)], x]^2]

epysl[x_, y_] := 
 Evaluate[
  D[ccu*Sin[(Pi*y)/aa]*Cos[(Pi*x)/(2*aa)] + (py*y)/(2*EE*hh*aa), y] + 
   1/2*D[wo*Cos[(Pi*x)/(2*aa)]*Cos[(Pi*y)/(2*aa)], y]^2]

epxysl[x_, y_] := 
 Evaluate[
  D[ccu*Sin[(Pi*x)/aa]*Cos[(Pi*y)/(2*aa)] + (px*x)/(2*EE*hh*aa), y] + 
   D[ccu*Sin[(Pi*y)/aa]*Cos[(Pi*x)/(2*aa)] + (py*y)/(2*EE*hh*aa), x] +
    D[wo*Cos[(Pi*x)/(2*aa)]*Cos[(Pi*y)/(2*aa)], x]*
    D[wo*Cos[(Pi*x)/(2*aa)]*Cos[(Pi*y)/(2*aa)], y]]


VVV = ((EE*hh)/(2*(1 - vv^2)))*
  Integrate[
   Integrate[
    epx[x, y]^2 + epy[x, y]^2 + 
     2*vv*epx[x, y]*epy[x, y] + ((1/2)/(1 - vv))*
      epxy[x, y]^2, {y, -aa, aa}], {x, -aa, aa}]
Out[]= 1/(9216 aa^2 EE hh (-1 + vv) (1 - 
   vv^2))(128 aa^2 (36 (-1 + vv) (px^2 + py^2 + 2 px py vv) + 
     ccu^2 EE^2 hh^2 (-64 + 128 (-1 + vv) vv + 
        9 \[Pi]^2 (-9 + 8 vv))) + 
  192 aa EE hh \[Pi]^2 (4 ccu EE hh (5 + 2 (-3 + vv) vv) + 
     3 (px + py) (-1 + vv^2)) woo^2 + 
  9 EE^2 hh^2 \[Pi]^4 (-10 + vv (8 + vv)) woo^4)
dVVVdc = D[%, ccu]

Out[]= (
256 aa^2 ccu EE^2 hh^2 (-64 + 128 (-1 + vv) vv + 
    9 \[Pi]^2 (-9 + 8 vv)) + 
 768 aa EE^2 hh^2 \[Pi]^2 (5 + 
    2 (-3 + vv) vv) woo^2)/(9216 aa^2 EE hh (-1 + vv) (1 - vv^2))

From this expression we can compute ccu as follows
solution = Solve[dVVVdc == 0, ccu]

Out[]= {{ccu -> -((3 \[Pi]^2 (5 - 6 vv + 2 vv^2) woo^2)/(
    aa (-64 - 81 \[Pi]^2 - 128 vv + 72 \[Pi]^2 vv + 128 vv^2)))}}

